# Get an attribute of a element bound to a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery plugin [tagEditor](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-tagEditor) and it has a parameter where you can enter a placeholder in; however I don't particularly want to hardcode this via the JS code, I would prefer for it to dynamically get the value via the actual fields `placeholder` attribute.

I managed to get this working using:

```
$('#tags').tagEditor({
    placeholder: $('#tags').attr('placeholder'),
});
```

However, again, I would prefer not to hardcode the id of the element in where it gets the placeholder from in-case I add a secondary selector.

I have tried to get it using `$(this)` but it doesn't appear to work (no value); eg:

```
$('#tags').tagEditor({
    placeholder: $(this).attr('placeholder'),
});
```

...produces an empty value.

Is there any way I can get the value without hardcoding in the element I want to get it from?

Comment: your code replacing placeholder with itself? what the point?

Comment: What do you mean? `#tags` is the `id` of the original _text field_ which I am binding the tagEditor to; I am trying to get the value of the `placeholder` attribute from the original text field so I can set it as the value of the tagEditor `placeholder` parameter.

Comment: got it, just never seen tagEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#tags').each(function(){    
  $(this).tagEditor( {  placeholder: $(this).attr('placeholder') } ); 
});
```

If you are worried about the performance due to `each`, here is an alternative

```
$.fn.myTagfunc = function(callback){
  callback.apply(this);
  return this;
};

$(selector).myTagfunc( function(){ 
     $(this).tagEditor({placeholder:$(this).attr('placeholder') });   
});
```